# Flutter testing results in "The getter 'flavor' was called on null."

Tags: flutter, dart, error-handling, integration-testing

I am doing Quality Assurance testing for this app and I want to test this individual page.

However I get the following error:

**NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'flavor' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: flavor**

The command I'm using is:

**flutter run --flavor dev -t ./lib/pages/welcome_page/welcome_page.dart**

I do not have another flavor I can use.

Is the flavor information supposed to have been passed on to this welcome_page.dart from the previous page?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:skinopathy_doctor/constants/constants.dart';
import 'package:skinopathy_doctor/constants/constants_strings.dart';
import 'package:skinopathy_doctor/pages/register/ohip/ohip_billing_page.dart';
import 'package:skinopathy_doctor/repositories/auth_repository.dart';
import 'package:skinopathy_doctor/repositories/doctor_profile_repository.dart';
import 'package:skinopathy_doctor/repositories/flavor_repostiory.dart';
import 'package:skinopathy_doctor/widgets/common/page_helper.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';



void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: WelcomePage(),
    );
  }
}


class WelcomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title = LocaleString.welcome_page_title;
  final String title_dev = "Welcome to closed Dev For Skinopathy!";
  final String description = LocaleString.welcome_page_description;

  WelcomePage();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
          width: displayWidth(context),
          height: displayHeight(context),
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
                fit: BoxFit.fill,
                image:
                    AssetImage('assets/images/backgroundImage/background.png')),
          ),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              _logoImage(context),
              _welcomeInfo(context),
            ],
          )),
    );
  }

  /*---------------------------------------------------------------------
    Showing app Name
  *--------------------------------------------------------------------*/
  Widget _welcomeInfo(BuildContext context) {
    return Expanded(
      child: Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(20),
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20, bottom: 10, top: 20),
        width: displayWidth(context),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white,
          borderRadius: new BorderRadius.all(
            Radius.circular(20.0),
          ),
          boxShadow: [
            BoxShadow(
              color: ColorPickers.mainColor.withAlpha(100),
              spreadRadius: 1,
              blurRadius: 3,
              offset: Offset(2, 2),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(FlavorConfig.isProduction() ? title : title_dev,
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: ColorPickers.darkBlackColor,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    fontSize: 22,
                    fontFamily: FontFamilyPickers.oswald)),
            SizedBox(
              height: 30,
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Text(description,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: ColorPickers.darkBlackColor,
                    fontSize: 18,
                  )),
            ),
            Container(
              width: displayWidth(context),
              alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
              child: TextButton(
                key: Key("buttonKey"),
                child: Text(LocaleString.welcome_next_button_text,
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: ColorPickers.darkBlackColor,
                        fontSize: 20,
                        fontFamily: FontFamilyPickers.oswald)),
                onPressed: () => _onConfirmationPressed(context),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  /*---------------------------------------------------------------------
    Image for logo
  *--------------------------------------------------------------------*/
  Widget _logoImage(BuildContext context) {
    return Expanded(
      child: Container(
        margin: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
        child: Center(
          child: Image.asset(ImagePaths.doctor_image),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _onConfirmationPressed(BuildContext context) async {
    // Check if user has previously registered.
    final uid = context.read<AuthRepository>().currentUser.uid;
    final docProfile =
        await context.read<DoctorProfileRepository>().getProfile(uid);

    // If doc has not registered
    if (docProfile == null)
      Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/register_new_doctor');
    // If registered, ensure that user has verified OHIP
    else if (!docProfile.hasVerifiedOHIP)
      Navigator.pushReplacement(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => OHIPBillingPage(doctorProfileInfo: docProfile),
        ),
      );
    // If all good
    else
      Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/patient_list');
  }
}
```